# The behavior of the Flutter app is too heavy when running on the Android emulator

Tags: android, flutter

I am making a Flutter app that plays videos using youtube_player_flutter.

It was completed for the time being, but when I tried running it on the Android emulator, it was a behavior that clearly felt strange. Looking at Flutter performance, it was 5-10fps.
This is hopeless.

However, when I run it on the actual iPhone, there is almost no discomfort at 30-60fps.

I'm not sure what caused this difference, but I can think of it as my mac book isn't big (not high spec) and often runs out of memory.

After all, does the performance of the emulator depend on the capacity of the running computer?
So, even if this phenomenon actually occurs, if I change the computer, the performance will change, and the behavior on the actual Android device will not necessarily match the behavior on the emulator that can be confirmed at present?

Comment: Try in actual Android device, before spending time to investigate the performance of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Of course, I'm trying if I can.
Unfortunately, I don't have an Android device.